# How to apply condition on view and dateFormat attribute on prime ng p-calendar control?

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have to use prime-ng p-calendar on turbo table rows which can  have two different date format - mm/yy and mm/dd/yy depending on period field value. For now, I have added this control twice and rendered control based on period field condition as shown below.

```
<p-calendar *ngIf="Period.length == 15" name="period"
  id="period"
  selectionMode="range"
  view="month"
  appendTo="body"
  dataType="string"
  formControlName="period"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [monthNavigator]="true"
  [yearNavigator]="true" 
  [dateFormat]="mm/yy"
  placeholder="Choose">
</p-calendar>

<p-calendar *ngIf="Period.length == 20" name="period"
  id="period"
  selectionMode="range"
  view="date"
  appendTo="body"
  dataType="string"
  formControlName="period"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [monthNavigator]="true"
  [yearNavigator]="true"  
  dateFormat="mm/dd/yy"
  placeholder="Choose">
 </p-calendar>
```

My question is how can I use one control that works for both date format? I know I need to apply condition on  view and dateFormat attribute but I am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind value and use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in your `dateFormat`. Basically you bind `dateFormat` to some condition, which in this case might be with a ternary (You can chain as many as you like but code can get unreadable preety fast).

Code will look like this:

```
<p-calendar 
  name="period"
  id="period"
  selectionMode="range"
  view="date"
  appendTo="body"
  dataType="string"
  formControlName="period"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [monthNavigator]="true"
  [yearNavigator]="true"  
  [dateFormat]="
  Period.length == 20 ? 'mm/dd/yy' : 
  Period.length == 15 ? 'mm/yy' : 
  'default value'"
  placeholder="Choose">
 </p-calendar>
```

just  make sure that you provide some default value if `Period` will have no length or length will be different than any of these values. And upon component initialization of the view `Period` should not be undefined if the condition really depends on the value of it.